# Hash Table traversal operation

Tags: c, data-structures, hashtable

I have following implementation of hash table of pointers to structures that represents active speech streams.

```
hash_table_t stream_buffers;
struct stream_struct *streamPtr =
              (struct streamPtr *) malloc(sizeof(struct stream_struct));
...
case CTRL_MSG_TYPE_STREAM_START_REQ:
(hash_table_insert(stream_buffers, stream_id, streamPtr));
```

When I receive a speech datagram from UDP socket I do a lookup and insert that datagram into the destined stream's local ring buffer.

```
if (hash_table_search(stream_buffers, _stream_id, (void **) &streamPtr))
{
  streamPtr->ringBuffer.entries[streamPtr->ringBuffer.head] = datagramBuff;
  memcpy(streamPtr->ringBuffer.entries[streamPtr->ringBuffer.head],
         2 * sizeof(uint16_t) + datagramBuff,
         streamPtr->framelegnth);
  streamPtr->ringBuffer.head =
         (streamPtr->ringBuffer.head + streamPtr->framelegnth)
         % streamPtr->ringBuffer.size;

  if (streamPtr->ringBuffer.filled < streamPtr->ringBuffer.size)
         streamPtr->ringBuffer.filled++;
}
```

Now I would like to process these speech frames from different streams in parallel. For that I need to traverse the Hash Table and collect all the pointers to active streams in a common Array that will be used as a parameter to a PARALLEL_FOR loop to act upon. My current Hash Table implementation does not have such operation. How can I implement one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing from the variable names and the subject of voice, and assumption of CMU's Sphinx project is being made

and except from hash_table.h from that project

```
typedef struct hash_entry_s {
        const char *key;
        size_t len;
        void *val;
        struct hash_entry_s *next;
} hash_entry_t;

typedef struct {
        hash_entry_t *table;
        int32 size;
        int32 inuse;
        int32 nocase;
} hash_table_t;
```

Based on these structures, you need to start with the `hash_entry_t` pointer `table` inside  the `hash_table_t` record.

Go along the chain of `next` pointers) from the head of that chain until you reach NULL.

The data you want to muster is probably kept in the `void` pointer `val` in each of those records, but I don't know for sure.  Check there to see if its a pointer to the data packets group you are looking for

EDIT

I suspect the function `hash_table_tolist( ... )` does what I just described

Comment: Looking at http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/doc/sphinxbase/hash__table_8h_source.html for hash_table.h

Comment: consider tagging this with one of stackoverflow's sphinx related tags if the guess was right.  I do not have karma to do that

Comment: Although I am not working with SPHINX neither using the said logic and data structures but your answer atleast pointed me to the direction I shall take to implement traversal operation. Thus marking the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

`parallel_for` is c++11, not c.   Are you really using C?

Comment: I am using C and capital letters are just to emphasize the programming paradigm. Please remove your answer and make it a comment.

Comment: not enough karma to comment yet.   Maybe someday soon

Comment: Since you are talking about voice, and reference a type hash_table_t I am going to guess that you are working with CMU's sphinx.  To collect all the entries in your hash table, you'd have to start with the head of your `hash_entry_s` list and follow the `next` pointer until you found NULL, saving each address as you go.  Maybe sphinx already has a method to do that, I'm just looking at the .h file